# Azure monitor not triggering alert

Tags: kql

I am trying to create an alert based on an event ID not existing.

```
  let Heartbeat = Event  
|where EventID ==9999 
|where Source == 'AIALERTS' 
|partition by Computer 
( 
   top 1 by TimeGenerated desc 
); 
let Server =InsightsMetrics 
|distinct Computer; 
Server 
|join kind = leftouter Heartbeat on Computer 
|extend HB = datetime_diff('Minute',now(),TimeGenerated) 
|extend Heart = iif(isnull(HB),100,HB) 
|project Heart,Computer
```

I have set the measure as the Heart measure and total by 5 min

No resource ID split

But I use computer as a dimension

I set the operator to greater then 1

But the preview so 0

When I run this in log analytics is works perfectly

Some of the computers of course, don't have an entry in the heart bet "let"

So I've tried to exclude them from the query incase its the time aggregation causing the issue but nada

```
let Heartbeat = Event  
|where EventID ==9999 
|where Source == 'AIALERTS' 
|partition by Computer 
( 
   top 1 by TimeGenerated desc 
); 
let Server =InsightsMetrics 
|distinct Computer; 
Server 
|join kind = leftouter Heartbeat on Computer 
|extend HB = datetime_diff('Minute',now(),TimeGenerated) 
|extend CT = iif(isnull(TimeGenerated),'A','B') 
|extend Heart = iif(isnull(HB),100,HB) 
|where CT =='B'
| summarize Counter = max(Heart) by bin(TimeGenerated, 5min), Computer
```

Comment: Some of the computer of course dont have an entry in the heart bet "let"

Answer (score 0):

The cause was when I'd set up the alert I'd some how managed not to set up the resource so it was overall the resources